# Acumatica data pull

Tags: acumatica

Good day

Is there a way to see what is pulling data out of the system and how much?
I have looked at the Access History(OData refresh) but I am thinking the API can also be an issue.

We currently experiencing massive data pulls via the IIS on our server and I can't see what is pulling the data.

Any ideas or suggestions will be helpful I

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor lots of things such as SQL and Memory through the Request Profiler.

Search for Request Profiler in the search box.

Click Log Requests and Log SQL to enable full logging.

Remember to turn it off when you are done as it will have a small performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the License Monitoring Console within Acumatica.  You can view historical transactions whether they are commercial or ERP related.

From the help file, commercial transactions are:

> Commercial transactions are a subset of ERP transactions. The system
> regards a transaction as commercial when the transaction creates or
> updates any of the following entities: sales orders, shipments,
> Accounts Receivable invoices, payments, purchase orders, purchase
> receipts, and Accounts Payable invoices. All requests generated by
> using the web services API that create or update data in these
> documents are also considered commercial transactions.

Also, you can review the number of web service API requests, requests per minute and maximum number of users.  This can also help determine whether your client needs to be on a higher tier for Acumatica.

You can also follow the troubleshooting recommendations listed on [Acumatica's help site](https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1e173168-12d7-43cf-82e4-a140237a700c).